# How to parse given string to DateTime?

Tags: .net, datetime, datetime-format

I have a JSON containing date array:

```
{
  "Date":[
          "Thu, 4 Jun 2020 10:37:43 +0000 (UTC)"
         ]
}
```

It is always a single cell array. I specify this format during deserialization:

```
DateTimeFormat = "ddd, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
```

and I get always the error:

> String 'Thu, 4 Jun 2020 12:07:50 +0000 (UTC)' was not recognized as
>   a valid DateTime.

**Question:** What is wrong with my datetime pattern?

Comment: The timezone part of the format string doesn't match the input. For that matter, .Net doesn't have that option built in (it expects +/-00:00 instead of +/-0000). You'll have to cut up the string some to adjust for that, as well as trimming off the timezone name.

Comment: If you control the json data, I suggest you store the dates in an ISO compliant format such as "2020-06-04T10:39:55+00:00"

Comment: @Mark No, unfortunately I don't control it, it's the way it is.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Is it possible to make the format reluctant so it tries to match as little as possible, so I would skip the timezone? I don't care about it.

Comment: @Yoda No, parsing dates is always strict. It's better this way; trust me.